# Load more button for ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 website

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to implement a `Load More` button for my website
https://mrnams.com

Can any one please give me an idea how to implement the `Load More` button to load more videos without refreshing (I mean without loosing loaded videos) page.

Similar to YouTube functionality.

I am using .net core 2.1 version

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate question. I'm actually looking forward to an answer for this.